# Representing multisets as LinkedLists

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, type-conversion

A multiset is similar to a set except that the duplications count.
  We want to represent multisets as linked lists. The first representation
  that comes to mind uses a `LinkedList<T>` where the same item can occur at
  several indices.
  For example:the multiset

```
{ "Ali Baba" , "Papa Bill", "Marcus", "Ali Baba", "Marcus", "Ali Baba" }
```

can be represented as a linked list
  of strings with "Ali Baba" at index 0, "Papa Bill" at index 1,
  "Marcus" at index 2, "Ali Baba" at index 3, and so on, for a total of
  6 strings.

The professor wants a representation of the multiset as `pair <item,integer>` where the integer, called the multiplication of item, tells us how many times item occurs in the multiset. This way the above multiset is represented as the linked list with Pair("Ali Baba" ,3) at index 0,  Pair("Papa Bill", 1) at index 1, and Pair("Marcus",2) at index 2.

The method is (he wrote good luck, how nice of him  >:[ )

```
public static <T>  LinkedList<Pair<T,Integer>> convert(LinkedList<T> in){

//good luck
}
```

the method transforms the first representation into the Pair representation.
  If in is null, convert returns null. Also feel free to modify the input list.

He gave us the Pair class-

```
public class Pair<T,S>
{

  // the fields

  private T first;

  private S second;


  // the constructor
  public Pair(T f, S s)
  {

     first = f;
     second = s;
  }

  // the get methods
  public T getFirst()
  {
     return first;
  }

  public S getSecond()
  {
     return second;
  }

// the set methods
  // set first to v
  public void setFirst(T v)
  {
     first = v;
  }

  // set second to v
  public void setSecond(S v)
  {
     second = v;
  }

}
```

I am new to programming and I've been doing well, however I have no idea how to even start this program. Never done something like this before.

Comment: Can you use other structures inside the convert method? The easiest way is to use `Map<String, Integer>` where key is element from list and value is counter of repetition. Then you iterate over `map.entrySet()` to populate list to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use a temporary `LinkedList` you could do something like that:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> test = new LinkedList<String>();
        test.add("Ali Baba");
        test.add("Papa Bill");
        test.add("Marcus");
        test.add("Ali Baba");
        test.add("Marcus");
        test.add("Ali Baba");
        LinkedList<Pair<String, Integer>> result = convert(test);
        for(Pair<String, Integer> res : result) {
            System.out.println(res.getFirst() + " :" + res.getSecond());
        }
    }

    public static <T> LinkedList<Pair<T, Integer>> convert(LinkedList<T> in) {
        LinkedList<Pair<T, Integer>> returnList = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<T> tmp = new LinkedList<T>();
        // iterate over your list to count the items
        for(T item : in) {
            // if you already counted the current item, skip it
            if(tmp.contains(item)) {
                continue;
            }
            // counter for the current item
            int counter = 0;

            //iterate again over your list to actually count the item
            for(T item2 : in) {
                if(item.equals(item2)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
            }
            // create your pair for your result list and add it
            returnList.add(new Pair<T, Integer>(item, counter));

            // mark your item as already counted
            tmp.add(item);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

With that i get the desired output of

```
Ali Baba :3
Papa Bill :1
Marcus :2
```

Comment: I am getting an error from your returnList.add(new Pair<T, Integer>(item, counter));

Comment: says - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Did you declare your returnList inside the method convert or as a class member? As your method is static the returnList must be declared inside of it!

Comment: Yes I declared it inside the method. I copied your code to test it out and it gave me that error :/

Comment: I just updated to have a full class that works together with your Pair class fine with me using OpenJDK 7 and Oracle JDK 8. I cannot get your compile error...

Comment: What platform/java version/ide do you use?

Comment: I just copied the whole method you wrote. And I got the same error on the line `returnList.add(new Pair<T, Integer>(item, counter));`

Comment: I am using netbeans IDE  8.0.2

Comment: Is your Pair class defined in the same file then the other code?

Comment: If your Pair class is in the same file it must also be declared static... public static class Pair...

Comment: Ok I was able to fix it. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements put:

- your input : LinkedList
- your output : LinkedList>

1 - write a loop to read your input

2 - process / store it in a convenient way: user Map . In fact, use linkedhashmap which keeps the order

2bis - if you can't use a Map, do the same thing directly with two arrays: an array of T, and an array of integer.  You must manager insertion, search, and keep count.

3 - iterate over your arrays, and create your output

It is easier to begin with 2, and if it works, replace with 2bis